# Creating a WCF service object with InstanceContext object

Tags: winforms, wcf, single-instance

I have a WCF service with a single instance. I have consumed it in silverlight and windows forms also. It's working fine in the silverlight application but in windows it does not create a service object.  It tells me 3 parameters in service method, like this:

```
InstanceContext, EndPoint, Binding
```

The 2nd and 3rd argument I have passed but as for the 1st argument *what should I use?* Please help me to consume this WCF single instance service in Windows forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new InstanceContext(yourSingletonServiceContarctImplementationInstance);
```